# Spring HTTP invoker alternative for Java EE?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs

we're developing standard Java SE application and it is *necessary* to implement some logic on remote server (using Java EE running on OpenShift PaaS). My question is, what is the best way to remote call classes/methods between the SE client and EE application?

My tips:

- **EJB remote call**: however, is the communication encrypted (or possibility to do that)?
- **Expose EBJs through JAX-RS**: looks line nice one, with possibility to use SSL encryption

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Title of this question indicates that the Java SE client is in Spring. If the PaaS provided allows, you can even choose Spring. That will help you in long term as the skillset to maintain your application will be small. It'll also improve efficiency.
JAX-RS is features provided by Spring and EJB are almost same.

Assuming you are bound to use EJBs, I'd suggest to go with 'Expose EBJs through JAX-RS'.

Pros -

1. It avoids tight coupling of client and service. Remote calls will make client aware of EJBs.
2. In future, you can choose to change your technology from EJB to something else, then client will be minimally impacted.
3. If you think to write client in any other technology than Java, then it'll be smooth.
4. Saves time related to JNDI setup

Cons -

1. Additional time for marshalling and un-marshalling.
2. Request-response convertes on client and server sides